# No touch scrolling when using `ttk.scrollbar` over `tk.scrollbar`

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, windows-10

I have discovered that using `tk.Scrollbar` allows use of touch the scroll on a text widget. When I was overhauling the graphics of my application I could no longer use touch to scroll the text widget that used `ttk.Scrollbar` instead.

I am positive it is a difference between the widgets because I have toggled between the two when testing the problem.

That being said it is not a huge problem, since only a handful of devices this program will be installed on will have touch capabilities.

Is there any way to get touch on a `ttk.scrollbar`?

EDIT: Relevant Section of Code:
EDIT #2: Added the two functions at the bottom

```
    self.text=tk.Text(self,font=("Consolas","11"),wrap="none",undo=True,bg="white",relief="flat")
    self.numb=tk.Text(self,font=("Consolas","11"),wrap="none",width=4,relief="flat")

    self.vsb=ttk.Scrollbar(self,command=self.scroller)
    self.hsb=ttk.Scrollbar(self,command=self.text.xview,orient="horizontal")

    self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.on_textscroll,xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
    self.numb.config(bg="grey94",yscrollcommand=self.on_textscroll)

def scroller(self,*args):#Move me
    self.text.yview(*args)
    self.numb.yview(*args)
def on_textscroll(self, *args):#Move me
    self.vsb.set(*args)
    self.scroller('moveto', args[0])
```

Comment: To get this correctly. What exactly are you referring to as "allows use of touch to scroll" ? In most devices, touch implementations use "click" behaviour. Do you mean that it allows you to click on a certan position inside the scrollbar-widget to move the slider into that direction / to that position?

Comment: @R4PH43L Sorry, I should have specified, this is using touch on the text widget itself. By this I mean moving up and down like I would on a word document or in notepad. It works when the scrollbars are tk, just not ttk.

Comment: Ok. Can you post the implementation you used inside your application?

Comment: @R4PH43L Updated question with relevant code.

Comment: I presume you mean finger touch and sliding.  It is odd that changing the scrollbar should affect the response to touch and slide on the text, as opposed to the bar. For tkinter Text with vscroll, such as `tkinter.scrolledtext`, pressing the middle mouse button while moving the mouse scrolls the text.  A fingers would do the same if treated as a middle mouse button. I just verified that Button-3 continues to work in a ScrolledText with a ttk.Scrollbar.  I wonder if the fact that you are scrolling two text widgets in syhchrony has any impact.  You do not show `self.scroller`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes - finger sliding: I've added the code you asked.

Comment: My previous comment should say Button-2, not Button-3.

Answer (score 0):

(Not necessarily an answer, but at least code to experiment with and maybe build upon to make an answer.)

The following scrolls in all directions with middle mouse button held down with either tk (line 2 commented out) or ttk Scrollbar (line 2 uncommented).

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Scrollbar
from tkinter.ttk import Scrollbar

class Test(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text = Text(self, wrap="none",undo=True,bg="white",relief="flat")
        self.numb = Text(self, wrap="none",width=4,relief="flat")

        self.vsb = Scrollbar(self,command=self.scroller)
        self.hsb = Scrollbar(self,command=self.text.xview,orient="horizontal")

        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.on_textscroll,xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
        self.numb.config(bg="grey94",yscrollcommand=self.on_textscroll)

        self.numb.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
        self.hsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')
        for i in range(100):
            self.text.insert('insert',
                ('abcdefg%2d   '%i)*10 + '\n')

    def scroller(self,*args):#Move me
        self.text.yview(*args)
        self.numb.yview(*args)
    def on_textscroll(self, *args):#Move me
        self.vsb.set(*args)
        self.scroller('moveto', args[0])

root=Test()
```

Adding the following at the end of **init** exposes middle mouse button clicks (it is botton 2, not 3), without disabling the scroll effect.  Do fingers touches trigger this, with either scrollbar?  If not, try to find out what event touches do generate.

```
        def pr(event):
            print(event)
        self.text.bind('<Button-2>', pr)
        self.text.bind('<ButtonRelease-2>', pr)
```

Comment: I have run through all the button options, including release and motions. They revealed nothing. Is there a way of printing all events a widget is involved with?

Comment: I looked through the sections in http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html and found <Any-Key> but not <Any-Event>.  My next guess is that on touch systems, finger touch and motion are defined as a virtual events.  You could try `root.event_info()` to list defined virtual events on regular and touch systems and see if the latter has extra events.  http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html#event_info